# To translate/to be translated

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> His name translates/is translated as 'lion'.

Are these alternatives both correct?

Answer (score 1):

You will hear both. Some people use "translate" as an intransitive verb that means the same thing as the passive form of the transitive verb "translate." Personally, I think it is a careless usage and prefer "is translated." But that's just what I consider careful English.